# Debug with VM angular.js on chrome console, I couldn't find where can I put the breakpoint to backtrace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I got `angular.js:11598 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'FormDemoCtrl' is not a function`

However, I could not use debugger to trace the root cause on chrome console. How could I find the start point to put the breakpoint?

Because the buggy point is located at the angular.js:11598
But I'm sure the bug is from my own code instead of inside of angular.js.
[image: inline]

DEMO page http://www.alphaloan.co/ngAdmin/admin.html#/app/form/elements

I tried to access the last state `loan.form.banks`

the controller is defined in `js/controllers/form.js`

```
  .config(
    [          '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'JQ_CONFIG', 
      function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider, JQ_CONFIG) {
          $urlRouterProvider
              .otherwise('/loan/form/banks');
          $stateProvider
              .state('loan', {
                  abstract: true,
                  url: '/loan',
                  templateUrl: 'tpl/admin.html',
              })
              .state('loan.form', {
                  url: '/form',
                  template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in"></div>',
                  resolve: {
                      deps: ['uiLoad',
                        function( uiLoad ){
                          return uiLoad.load('js/controllers/form.js');
                      }]
                  }
              })
              .state('loan.form.banks', {
                  url: '/banks',
                  templateUrl: 'tpl/admin_banks.html',
                  resolve: {
                      deps: ['uiLoad',
                        function( uiLoad ){
                          return uiLoad.load('js/controllers/form.js');
                      }]
                  }
              })
        }]
```

## Exception on console

```
VM17515 angular.js:11598Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'FormDemoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/ng/areq?p0=FormDemoCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
    at assertArg (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1577:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1587:3)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8422:9
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7596:34
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:331:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7583:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7075:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6954:30)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3905:9(anonymous function) @ VM17515 angular.js:11598(anonymous function) @ VM17515 angular.js:8548invokeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:8219nodeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7726compositeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7075publicLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:6954updateView @ angular-ui-router.js:3839(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.js:3807invokeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:8217nodeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7726compositeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7075publicLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:6954(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.js:3905invokeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:8217nodeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7726compositeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7075publicLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:6954updateView @ angular-ui-router.js:3839(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.js:3807invokeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:8217nodeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7726compositeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7075compositeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7078publicLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:6954(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.js:3905invokeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:8217nodeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7726compositeLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:7075publicLinkFn @ VM17515 angular.js:6954updateView @ angular-ui-router.js:3839(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.js:3801Scope.$broadcast @ VM17515 angular.js:14707$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition @ angular-ui-router.js:3218processQueue @ VM17515 angular.js:13175(anonymous function) @ VM17515 angular.js:13191Scope.$eval @ VM17515 angular.js:14388Scope.$digest @ VM17515 angular.js:14204$delegate.__proto__.$digest @ VM17549:844Scope.$apply @ VM17515 angular.js:14493$delegate.__proto__.$apply @ VM17549:855(anonymous function) @ VM17515 angular.js:16219completeOutstandingRequest @ VM17515 angular.js:4902(anonymous function) @ VM17515 angular.js:5282
2admin.html#/app/form/elements:1 The specified value "appledaily.com.tw" is not a valid email address.
```

## Updated

The `controllers/bootstrap.js` is loaded in the admin.html,

However, other controllers not loaded.  That is because other controllers are loaded by the 
`$stateProvider`

```
                  resolve: {
                      deps: ['uiLoad',
                        function( uiLoad ){
                          return uiLoad.load('js/controllers/form.js');
                      }]
                  }
```

### index.html

```
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.admin.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.lazyload.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.admin.router.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/ui-load.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: You forgot close `]` bracket in your `config`. Where is your `FormDemoCtrl`? I can not find it in your controller folder.

Comment: No, I appended it, but that's not the root cause, just TYPO. my FormDemoCtrl is located at `js/controllers/form.js` this is also not the buggy point to. it did load with the ui.load service. I got the file not found by changing it to `../js/controllers/form.js`

Comment: Can you check that again? I just found the bootstrap.js in your controller folder, there is no form.js

Comment: @DieuNQ thanks so much, I guess there are some problems the those files not loaded in server, cause this is the folder structure `controllers
├── bootstrap.js
├── chart.js
├── editor.js
├── file-upload.js
├── form.js
├── grid.js
├── imgcrop.js
├── largeLoad.json
├── scroll.js
├── select.js
├── signin.js
├── signup.js
├── slider.js
├── tab.js
├── table.js
├── toaster.js
├── tree.js
├── uigrid.js
├── upload.php
├── uploads
├── vectormap.js
└── xeditable.js`

Comment: @DieuNQ Please take a look on my updated section

Comment: May your problem is load files to server. Because I still not found form.js

Comment: @DieuNQ No, I made it work after inserting `  <script src="js/controllers/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/form.js"></script>`, However, I'm still figuring out the magic of lazyLoad, uiLoad, and resolve ~~ haha it's overwhelming